# Java - JAX RS Jersey2 MultiPart 415 Response

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, multipartform-data

I'm working on a RESTful service (On **TomEE**) and need to use `multipart/form-data` in order for file uploading as well as passing additional JSON. Using Jersey 2, I've included all needed dependencies (including `jersey-media-multipart` and even `mimepull`)

I've written a simple resource method as such:

```
@POST
@Path("/upload")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response upload(@FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadInputStream,
                        @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition contentDisposition, 
                        @FormDataParam("details") UploadDetails uploadDetails) {
    // processing
}
```

Making a call from **Postman** leads to `415 Unsupported Media Type` and the stacktrace is as such:

> SEVERE: No message body reader has been found for class
>   org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataContentDisposition,
>   ContentType:
>   multipart/form-data;boundary=--------------------------152775525417017934208524
>
> Apr 18, 2018 3:33:55 PM
>   org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.WebApplicationExceptionMapper toResponse
>
> WARNING: javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: HTTP 415 Unsupported
>   Media Type
>   at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.readFromMessageBody(JAXRSUtils.java:1346)

No message body reader has been found for class `FormDataContentDisposition`. When using other variables such as `FormDataMultiPart`, the same exception appears.

Things to **note**:

I have registered MultipartFeature in the main class (that extends Application):

```
@Override
public Map<String, Object> getProperties() {
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put("jersey.config.server.provider.classnames", "org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature");
    return props;
}
```

I have also looked at all posts in SO regarding this issue and nothing seemed to help.

I cannot find how it happens. Perhaps there's something I am missing to see here?

**EDIT:**

The marked Duplicate does not help in my case.

Comment: can you check content type in the request

Comment: @PrasadReddy Content type in the request is indeed `Content-Type: multipart/form-data;`. Lately I have been reading about not being able to find MessageBodyReader, and since I am not using Spring I think there's some additional configuration needed from my side, but I have no luck so far finding the issue.

Comment: Can you check this example https://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/file-upload-example-in-jersey/  .. Try to find if anything is missing from that. Might be a dependency issue.

Comment: @PrasadReddy Already checked that one.. I'm headed towards a different direction now. I'm running on TomEE which for JAX-RS uses CXF implementation (which could be seen from the stacktrace) and not Jersey (which I am using in my restful service). Following this: [Default CXF Providers](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-basics.html#JAX-RSBasics-MessageBodyProviders) It seems like these are the types supported by CXF and I think I need to change the way I'm handling the request in order to comply with CXF.